# Why so many noob questions are down voted in Data Science?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to Data Science and I was surprised to see many basic questions down voted.
See this [example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22123/why-do-we-use-a-loss-function-for-backpropagation-rather-than-just-the-absolute).

The asker has not understood something and actually the comment by @Emre is a good answer and can help many people having the same question.

Since the comment was up voted 5 times, it means that the question was not so stupid/irrelevant/[your definition of bad question].

If we down vote each question that the right answer is RTFM, StackExchange should have 80% of its questions with a negative score.

It also prevent some people to ask good questions fearing to be down voted.

What do you think?

PS: please do not down vote my first question on Meta ;)

Comment: _"PS: please do not down vote my first question on Meta ;)"_ Since they do not influence your reputation on the main site, it doesn't really make sense to ask this. Why can't we show our disagreement here in the form of downvotes?

Comment: @E_net4 I just wrote this (the PS) as a joke and hopefully have a good question.

Comment: As for your concern, I don't think this is very alarming. Questions that leave significant room for improvement will eventually attract downvotes. And anyway, that question only has a score of -1 at the time of writing.

Comment: Neural networks are rather new for many people so writing a good question and not opinion based is rather difficult. Is this tool is good? Is this one is better? are basic questions that every beginner ask themselves. Advanced users may help in this case, but since they are bad questions they will be closed. Perhaps a section of StackExchange for opinion based questions may be opened.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't downvote it, but think it's not wrong. The asker didn't seem to try to research the question, because it would have been clear quickly that the question's premise doesn't quite make sense.

One thing StackExchange does seem to reward is well-researched questions, where the asker is investing time just like the answerers are requested to. And so SEs do discourage questions that don't seem to show effort. And yes, most questions on SE sites are bad, IMHO. Fortunately voting surfaces the 5% that are useful.

The question wasn't closed or anything, someone just registered an opinion about it. If someone takes it personally and doesn't ask more questions, well, probably not the place for it. SE does not have to be the right resource for everyone.

The sites can be fine for newbies, if they're asking thoughtful questions that are not readily answered already. Most newbie questions tend to be already answered somewhere, so they're more frequently downvoted here. So SEs seem like they are more suitable for experienced practitioners.